vue 3 auto scroll to newly added list item in a quasar list with quasar area scroll
I am trying to get auto scroll to a newly added item in my q-list > q-scroll-area component. Everything I have tried is not working all I get is a flashing scroll bar and then nothing. this is what I found in the quasar documentation and what I have tried as a watcher
Scrolling to an element
Below is an example using the scroll utils to scroll to an element within its container. It does not take into consideration if the container is on screen or more complex cases.

import { scroll } from 'quasar'
const { getScrollTarget, setVerticalScrollPosition } = scroll

// takes an element object
function scrollToElement (el) {
  const target = getScrollTarget(el)
  const offset = el.offsetTop
  const duration = 1000
  setVerticalScrollPosition(target, offset, duration)
}

this is my watcher.

// Watch for changes in the filteredList
watch(
    () => filteredList,
    () => {
        // Scroll to the selectedAssetItem when it changes
        if (filteredList.value && scrollArea.value) {
            const selectedItemElement =
                scrollArea.value.querySelector('.active-item') as HTMLElement;
            if (selectedItemElement) {
                const target = getScrollTarget(scrollArea.value);
                const offset = selectedItemElement.offsetTop;
                const duration = 1000;
                setVerticalScrollPosition(target, offset, duration);
            }
        }
    }
);

but as I said im getting no scrolling to the new item
can some one please point me in the right direction on how I could get this done ?
I am still new to quasar so I do not know all the little tricks of it yet .
thanks
Edit 1 : here is more of my code of my component as requested this is my q-list with my active-item inside the v-for and q-scroll area.
<q-list
            v-model="selectedAssetItem"
            separator
            bordered
            padding
            class="rounded-borders"
        >
            <q-item class="no-right-padding">
                <q-toolbar>
                    <q-toolbar-title class="text-white">Assets</q-toolbar-title>
                    <q-btn
                        flat
                        round
                        v-if="assetStore.mode === Mode.Delete"
                        @click="onAllAssetsClick"
                    >
                        <q-icon size="sm" name="done_all" color="blue" />
                    </q-btn>
                </q-toolbar>
            </q-item>
            <q-scroll-area
                ref="scrollArea"
                style="height: calc(100vh - 110px)"
                class="scroll-area"
            >
                <div
                    class="asset-item-container"
                    v-if="assetStore.mode !== Mode.Delete"
                >
                    <asset-item
                        v-for="(item, index) in filteredList"
                        :key="index"
                        :item="item"
                        :class="{
                            'active-item': item.name === selectedAssetItem,
                        }"
                        @click="selectItem(item, index)"
                    />
                </div>
                <div
                    class="asset-item-container"
                    v-if="assetStore.mode === Mode.Delete"
                >
                    <asset-item-checkbox
                        v-for="(item, index) in filteredList"
                        :key="index"
                        :item="item"
                    />
                </div>
            </q-scroll-area>
        </q-list>

Edit 2: I have tested my watcher it is working as my item is getting selected but it still seems even though I am getting the item the scrolling is still not working. this is what i have now based on the stackblitz example and further edits to my code
the watch 
/**
 * highlights the newly added asset
 */
watch(filteredList, (newList, oldList) => {
    if (newList.length > oldList.length) {
        const newItem = newList.find(
            (item) => !oldList.some((oldItem) => oldItem.id === item.id)
        );
        if (newItem) {
            selectedAssetItem.value = newItem.name;
            const itemElement = document.querySelector('.asset-item') as HTMLElement | undefined;
            scrollToItem(itemElement);
        }
    }
});

the scrollToItem function
// Function to scroll to a specific item
const scrollToItem = (element: any) => {
      const target = getScrollTarget(element);
      const offset = element.offsetTop;
      const duration = 1000;
      setVerticalScrollPosition(target, offset, duration);
};




Is the watcher running? Are you corrrectly getting the element? We need to see more of your code to find the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-gzhf53?file=src%2Fpages%2FIndexPage.vue

I have added more of my code to the question

@fOURP in your example on stackblitz you have a q-list with a q-item then scrolling with the q-item. I have a q-scroll-area, when i apply your scrolling example the q-scroll-area only scrolls a little bit not to the exatct Item like yours does .. is there any additional logic I need  to deal with the q-scroll-area to make this work.. it is almost there . just seems to be missing something ?

The issue has been resolved I had to redesign my list component to not include the q-scroll-area this is how it looks now
    <div id="asset-list">
        <div id="list-header">
            <q-toolbar>
                <q-toolbar-title class="text-white">Assets</q-toolbar-title>
                <q-btn
                    flat
                    round
                    v-if="assetStore.mode === Mode.Delete"
                    @click="onAllAssetsClick"
                >
                    <q-icon size="sm" name="done_all" color="blue" />
                </q-btn>
            </q-toolbar>
        </div>
        <div id="list-container">
            <q-list
                v-model="selectedAssetItem"
                separator
                bordered
                class="rounded-borders"
            >
                <div
                    class="asset-item-container"
                    v-if="assetStore.mode !== Mode.Delete"
                >
                    <asset-item
                        v-for="(item, index) in filteredList"
                        :key="item.id"
                        :id="`asset-${item.id}`"
                        :item="item"
                        :class="{
                            'active-item': item.name === selectedAssetItem,
                        }"
                        @click="selectItem(item, index)"
                    />
                </div>
                <div
                    class="asset-item-container"
                    v-if="assetStore.mode === Mode.Delete"
                >
                    <asset-item-checkbox
                        v-for="(item, index) in filteredList"
                        :key="index"
                        :item="item"
                    />
                </div>
            </q-list>
        </div>
    </div>

and I updated the watch with the scrollToItem function like this
/**
 * highlights the newly added asset
 */
watch(filteredList, (newList, oldList) => {
    if (newList.length > oldList.length) {
        const newItem = newList.find(
            (item) => !oldList.some((oldItem) => oldItem.id === item.id)
        );

        if (newItem) {
            selectedAssetItem.value = newItem.name;
            scrollToItem(newItem.id);
        }
    }
});

and now the big part the scrollToItem function
// Function to scroll to a specific item
const scrollToItem = (selector: string | number | undefined) => {
    nextTick(() => {
        const el = document.querySelector(`#asset-${selector}`) as HTMLElement;
        const listContainer = document.getElementById(
            'list-container'
        ) as HTMLElement;

        if (el && listContainer) {
            const offset = el.offsetTop - listContainer.offsetTop;
            const duration = 100;
            animVerticalScrollTo(listContainer, offset, duration);
        }
    });
};

thanks for the example from fOURP I was able to use that in the resolution to my issue.
